# Unable to query for Users CKRecords

Tags: ios, iphone, cloudkit

With this query on the *public database*:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "family == %@", ref)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Users", predicate: pred)
```

I get no results, even though I have this reference association on two `Users` records.

Even if I try:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Users", predicate: pred)
```

Which *should* return all `Users` records, I get nothing. Though I’d understand that Apple might not want the latter, is it also the case that I cannot query for specific Users as well?

I have scoured the documentation, but it's a little lacking currently and cannot find any conditionals about this. `Users` is a special recordType, so perhaps the answer is simply "No you cannot query for Users".

Thanks.

Comment: you can query... but return all users: `discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User records are explicitly not queryable. You must use `CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation`, `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation`, `-[CKContainer discoverUserInfo...]` or `-[CKContainer discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler]` to find a user record.

If you need to query on an attribute of a user you'll need to create a new record type and store the property in there. You can use `creatorUserRecordID` on your custom record to associate that value with the user.